# Terminating app

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is the function I am using in my code:

```
 -(id) initFromNormalSprite:(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>*)normalSprite
        selectedSprite:(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>*)selectedSprite
          activeSprite:(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>*)activeSprite
        disabledSprite:(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol>*)disabledSprite
                  name:(NSString*)name
                target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector
```

{
    if (( self = [super initFromNormalSprite:normalSprite
                           selectedSprite:selectedSprite
                           disabledSprite:disabledSprite
  target:target selector:selector]))
    {
        self.activeImage = activeSprite;
        self.name = name;

```
    // TODO, create an addSpriteFrameByName extension
    CCSpriteFrameCache* fcache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
    NSString* glowName = @"frames-glow.png";

    if([fcache spriteFrameByName: glowName]) {
    } else {
        CCTexture2D* glowTex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage      imageNamed:glowName]];
        CCSpriteFrame* spriteFrame = [[CCSpriteFrame alloc] initWithTexture:glowTex
        rect:CGRectMake(0,0,glowTex.pixelsWide,glowTex.pixelsHigh)];
       //offset: ccp(0,0)];
        [fcache addSpriteFrame:spriteFrame name:glowName];
       [spriteFrame release];
        [glowTex release];
    }
    self.glow = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:glowName];
    self.showGlow = true;
}
return self;
}
```

It's building fine but crashes in simulator with the following:

2010-12-24 23:22:48.417 PanelsExample[8967:207] *** Assertion failure in -[NMPanelMenuItem addChild:z:tag:], /Users/aeshverma/Downloads/jashmenn-shapes-panels-bcf4e74/cocos2d/CCNode.m:360
2010-12-24 23:22:48.430 PanelsExample[8967:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'child already added. It can't be added again'

please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but it appears as though you could be adding the texture multiple times to the CCSpriteFrameCache.  The best way to identify this problem is to execute the game with debugging, and when it "breaks" ... launch the Debugger window, and step backwards to where your code is and identify the line of code that is causing the problem - then work from there.

This also seems like an improper use of a custom class as well, but that's a discussion for another topic.